# Resizable UIImage and retina

Tags: ios, uikit, uiimage, retina-display

I am not sure what middle size I should use for the stretchable part of a retina image. The document says:

> During scaling or resizing of the image, areas covered by a cap are
>   not scaled or resized. Instead, the pixel area not covered by the cap
>   in each direction is tiled, left-to-right and top-to-bottom, to resize
>   the image. This technique is often used to create variable-width
>   buttons, which retain the same rounded corners but whose center region
>   grows or shrinks as needed. For best performance, use a tiled area
>   that is a **1x1 pixel** area in size.

But aren't retina images supposed to be 2x the size of non-retina images? If so, shouldn't the middle be 1x1 **point** == 2x2 pixel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both 1x1 pixel and 2x2 pixel areas will work. 1x1 may get you more performance as per docs, but 2x2 is much more convenient for scaling down retina size resources.